# how to define data parsley pattern for limit number?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I'm using Parsley, and it's great! I want to define different patterns in data-parsley-pattern to limit just 10 number input in a field.

for example 01234567897.

Comment: it is in javascript but i want it in data-parsley-pattern="????"

Comment: RTM? http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validator-pattern

Comment: data-parsley-length="[10, 10]"

Answer (score 1):

i solve it:

```
data-parsley-length="[10, 10]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

`pattern="^[0-9]{1,10}$"`